# dynamically generated html buttons, ng-click not working on button click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the below code, where based on the rest call, a list of buttons gets generated. I need to display a screen on the right side of the page when a button is clicked. The screen varies depending on the button that is being clicked.

Below is the code for populating the Button dynamically

```
var app = angular.module("HConfigureModule",[]);
app.controller('HConfigureController',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
$scope.myvalue = false;
$scope.configurePList= function(){
    $scope.result = "" ;
    $scope.searchValue = "";
    $scope.namelist=[];
    $scope.myvalue = true; 
    var protocol = window.location.protocol;
    var hostDetails = window.location.host;
    var instanceDetails = window.location.pathname;
    var url = protocol + "//" + hostDetails
    + instanceDetails + "index";
    //alert(url+'/getPluginsList.html');
    var response = $http.get(url+'/getPlugList.html');
    response.success(function(qResult){
        var tst = qResult ;
        var len = tst.length;
        $scope.numStorages = len ;

        var i;
        var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector('#connListDiv') );
        for(i=0;i<len;i++)
            {

        $scope.result = myEl.append('<button type="button" style="word-wrap:break-word" ng-click="display1();" class="btn btn-default pluginClass dummy">'+qResult[i].name+'</button>');
                $scope.namelist.push(qResult[i].name) ;
            }

    });
    var testbutton = angular.element(document.querySelector('.dummy'));
    testbutton.bind('click', $scope.display1());
   };
```

Below is the code for display1()

```
    $scope.display1 = function(){
    var  expluclass = angular.element( document.querySelector('.existingPluginClass')) ;
        expluclass.show() ;
        var nplugclass = angular.element( document.querySelector('.newPluginClass')) ;
        nplugclass.hide();
        angular.element( document.querySelector('.connDivClass')).hide();
        var link = angular.element( document.querySelector('.pluginClass'));
        link.removeClass("btn-primary");
       var plugName = link.text().trim();
        alert(plugName);
        if(plugName == "HFS")
            angular.element( document.querySelector('#connPropsDivHFS')).show();
        else{
            angular.element( document.querySelector('#connPropsDivOthers')).show();
            var protocol = window.location.protocol;
            var hostDetails = window.location.host;
            var instanceDetails = window.location.pathname;
            var url = protocol + "//" + hostDetails
            + instanceDetails + "index";
            //alert(url+'/getPluginsList.html');
            var response = $http.get(url+'/getSelectedPDetails.html?pluginName='+plugName);
            response.success(function(queryResult){


            });
        }
    }
```

The issue Im facing here is, Based on the getPlugList.html response, there are around 10 button generated dynamically.But the button click works only once during the first time.Since the buttons are generated dynamically,I had to use the bind the click event to the button.

**Help Required**
   Can you please let me know if there is an option available to make the ng-click work even after the initial load. I.e I wanted the display1() to be invoked everytime when one of the 10 buttons is clicked.

Any help on this is much appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Comment: You are looking for `$compile`. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: Angular programmers usually use directives such as `ng-repeat` and `ng-if` to build DOM dynamically. Those directives can instantiate `ng-click`and other directives in such a away that there are no memory leaks when DOM is destroyed.